# Change author permalink

Tags: permalinks, author, mod-rewrite

The original urls for users look like `/author/login/`

**Is it possible to replace login by user's id?**

In my dream urls should become to `/users/34/` (34 is user id).

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use user IDs instead of user names? IDs are very user unfriendly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need 3 simple functions and hooks

first change the author base:

```
//change author/username base to users/userID
function change_author_permalinks() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
   // Change the value of the author permalink base to whatever you want here
   $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'users';
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```

then add users to query_vars:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'users_query_vars');
function users_query_vars($vars) {
    // add lid to the valid list of variables
    $new_vars = array('users');
    $vars = $new_vars + $vars;
    return $vars;
}
```

then add the new rewrite rule:

```
function user_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $newrules = array();
  $new_rules['users/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]';
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules','user_rewrite_rules');
```

Now if you don't know how to use this, just copy all of the code and paste in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: the last remark is for new users :)

Comment: You are aware an `'init'` hook with a `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules()` can bring a site to it's knees, right? I just had to do emergency debugging for a client using a plugin that did that; it was taking up to 90 seconds to load a page. Commenting out that line brought page loads down to less than 1 second. `flush_rules()` need to go in a plugin activation hook, or at least be surrounded by an `if (get_option(...)) {...}`.

Comment: +1 Mike - Also my concern, i was about to post a similar comment, let's not encourage users to flush rules on init.

Comment: @Mike , @t31os: So  you are saying that `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` should only run once (say on  activation) , and the setup should be run on every init?

Comment: Correct. I've been toying with the idea of using `getlastmod()` and an option value to run `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` only once after the `.php` file is changed; that might be a good way to go that would not require creating a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an htaccess rule to rewrite /users/34 to /?author=34

Comment: Since there are ways to do this with WordPress plugins I'd personally recommend avoiding the complexity of `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

I built a plugin to do this. A friend wanted to hide his author URL's as he didn't like the fact they were displaying his author's usernames. I decided to go one further and allow any user to set their own URL. It redirects their old author pages. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-author-url/

Comment: Thank you very much !! Your plugin save me !!