# Change author permalink using htaccess?

Tags: permalinks, author, htaccess

The original urls for users look like /author/user-name/

Is it possible to replace login by user's id? (something like: /author/34/ (34 is user id)).

I found the solution given [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13330/change-author-permalink), to not work for my site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it's simpler to do this via your theme's functions.php or a plugin rather than .htaccess:

```
function wpse31040_author_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'author/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?author=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse31040_author_rewrite' );
```

make sure to visit the permalinks settings page after adding this to flush rewrite rules.